# excel, filter on, shift column values to the left

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a filter on. I need to shift column values to the left. Please see below screenshot.

In below screenshot, I want to delete Name1 - Name5 and shift all the cells on the right to the left. I can't do this. Excel will not let me. It wants me to delete the entire row which I do not want to do.

I also do not want to use the = next column formula since there are 50+ columns in this spreadsheet. So I need some help and advice.

I have tried to highlight the first Home to Address5 and drag that to the left, then get error message

```
The command you chose cannot be performed with multiple selections. Select a single range and click the command again.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4xxw.png)

Comment: As the error message says, you can't do it with multiple frames selected. Try to sort by `primary_flag` before filtering it.

Comment: "In below screenshot, I want to delete Name1 - Name5 and shift.." In the attached screenshot, there is no such object as `Name1` or `Name5`. Please edit your question to clarify your request.

Comment: Your Screen shot is different than the issue you have raised ,,, Filter & Delete are two different issue !!